# How to list branches which are in remote A but not in remote B with git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

For example if I have a "main" upstream repository where I develop, and a side-repository where I backup my work after a finished work-day - now I want to delete branches on the side-repository which are not in the "main" repository are anymore, because they are merged (or whatever).

How to list branches which exist in the "side" remote but not in the "main" remote?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have a second repository for backing up your work? Surely the fact that you have a local and remote version of the same repository gives you enough of a backup?

Comment: Because I have two (actually four) remotes I have to work with. Git is distributed, not centralized! Having multiple remotes costs nothing and if one breaks (disc failure, whatever) I can continue working without doing anything.

Comment: The cost is the extra work involved in trying things like in your question above. If your remote is hosted then it is backed up already. You will have you're local copy and the copy in the remote repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - incorporated feedback from torek
**UPDATE 2** - small but potentially important change to suggested scripting

---

Well, git doesn't think in terms of a branch existing in multiple repos.  You have branches in your local repo, and you have snapshots of the branches in any given remote... and the local branch may have the same name as a branch on the remote, but it still isn't "the same branch" to git.

Only tracking provides something of an illusion that "the same branch" is in two repos.  (And only as a matter of convention is it typical to have the local branch named the same as the remote branch.)  This, too, is limited in that you can't have one local branch track two remote branches...

Which is a long way of saying, I don't think git alone can do what you're asking; you'll likely need to post-process some git output in some way.

You can get the list of branches that are in a remote by saying

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/<remote-name>
```

You could use cut to get just the basic branch name (`cut -d\/ -f 4-`).  (Note that trailing `-`, which is important if/only if you have branch names containing `/`.)  Then sort.  Then feed to `comm` to see which lines appear in both, or in only one.

Comment: For scripting, it's much better to use `git for-each-ref`, which can do name patterns: `git for-each-ref refs/remotes/A` to get all the remote-tracking branch names you currently have saved for remote `A`, for instance. Toss in appropriate `--format` directives and, as you suggested, use `comm` or similar to identify unique and shared ones. Another option is to use `git ls-remote` to consult a remote for its names as of Right Now, though of course by the time you get the answer, it's probably literally *seconds* out of date.

Comment: Not following your reasoning about `for-each-ref` vs `branch --list`.  `branch --list` *also* supports patterns (as used in my example); is there a difference in how the pattern is interpreted (and would it matter for this use case)?  `ls-remote` is an interesting option; I wasn't aware of *any* remote-interacting commands other than push/pull/fetch.  It is an interesting option if there's any concern about the local repo's remote refs being out of date

Comment: The main problem with `git branch` is that it is what Git calls a *porcelain* command, i.e., aimed at users. As it is porcelain, the Git maintainers feel free to change the output format arbitrarily if they feel the result is more readable or useful. It might, for instance, suddenly begin column-sorting its output a la Unix/Linux `ls`. As for other Git commands that contact remotes, `git remote` will do so under various circumstances, too (it's not useful for this particular case though).

Comment: Hmm... in the past I've specifically steered people *toward* porcelain commands, but for scripting purposes I do see your point.  (The specific example seems like a non-issue since there are already options to control columns in `branch --list` output, but the general principle is valid.)

Comment: Good lord, `--column` has been around since 1.7.11!  I never noticed it in the documentation. :-) The other pain in the butt for `git branch`, which was required back when `for-each-ref` did not implement `--contains` and `--merged` and so on, is that the current branch gets the `*` prefix, and all branch names get shortened with potential ambiguity (is `x/y` a local branch `x/y` or a remote-tracking branch `y` on remote `x`?).

Comment: Ah... the `*` wasn't on my mind because we're talking remote branches, but the possibility of `/` in branch names is concerning.  (Another of those things I tend to forget about, because I've only worked one place that ever did that.)  I'll make another tweak or two to my answer...